# Creating folders from file names using only part of the file name

Tags: python, split, directory, path, glob

I would like to move files that exists in a directory into new folders that hold specific string from the names of the files.
Here are examples for file names I have in the directory (out of thousands):

```
WS1_APAL4900.pdf
WS1_APAL4900_A.pdf
WS1_APAL4900_B.pdf
WS1_APAL4900_C.pdf
WS1_CANM0901.pdf
WS1_CANM0901_A.pdf
WS2_CANM0901.pdf
WS2_CANM0901_A.pdf
WS3_CANM0901.pdf
WS3_CANM0901_A.pdf
WS3_CONT6565.pdf
```

My goal is to split the name of the files on the underscore/s delimiters into 2 or 3 strings and to take only the second one from the left, which holds a 8 word/digit string and create the new folders from it, with a name like that: 'MFMO1720', whether it is a name with 2 or 3 strings.
Now, all files that have the 8-characters right of the first underscore from the left, regardless if they do not have OR do have _A, _B, etc. in their name, should be moved into the new folder with their 8-character name.

For now, when I run the code the files with '_x' are gathered all under one folder (i.e 'APAL4900' folder holds 'WS1_APAL4900_A.pdf',     'WS1_APAL4900_B.pdf' and     'WS1_APAL4900_C.pdf', but not 'WS1_APAL4900.pdf'). Files that do NOT have _A, _B, _C, etc. go into a folder that has the .pdf extention in their name, ie. 'APAL4900.pdf' holds only one file (WS1_APAL4900.pdf).

I tried split() and rsplit() and also other splitting methods, but none of them helps me get all the files with the same 8-character number to the same folder.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the code:

````
folder = 'C:/test'

for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, '*.*')):
    new_dir = file_path.rsplit('_', 2)[1]
    try:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(folder, new_dir))
    except WindowsError:
        # Handle the case where the target dir already exist.
        pass
    shutil.move(file_path, os.path.join(new_dir, os.path.basename(file_path)))```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep it basic, without regular expressions, you could just replace '.' with '_' before splitting.

So something like (instead of your new_dir assignment):

```
new_dir = file_path.replace('.', '_').split('_')[1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dolfa. It does exactly what I want!

Comment: Great. Just please accept Javier or mine answer to mark it as resolved. (I dont think you can accept yours answer, but if you could, just go ahead.)

Answer (score 0):

To add to Dolfa's answer. If you do want to use regular expressions you could do something like this:

```
import re
new_dir = re.split("_([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(_|\.)", file_path)[1]
```

This regular expression basically does the following:

- `_` matches the character _
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` matches 0 or more
  characters in the range a-z, A-Z or 0-9
- `_|\.` matches the character _ or .

Which will output:

```
APAL4900
APAL4900
APAL4900
APAL4900
CANM0901
CANM0901
CANM0901
CANM0901
CANM0901
CANM0901
CONT6565
```

One of the advantages of using a regular expression is that if your filename convention were to change to something more complex, you can easily adapt it to capture what you want. In your case since it is a simple string match it is not necessary, as it would simply add overhead.

Comment: Thank you Javier.
Indeed, this got a bit more complex now that I found that a file with white space (WS1_HCUL0004 _A.pdf') throws an error. Maybe this is the place to add Regex?

Comment: @AviadGiat I would recommend simply doing another replace like so `.replace(" ", "")` because this will remove any white spaces at any position.

Answer (score 0):

That works perfectly Javier.
Here is the final code:

```
folder = 'C:/Test'

for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, '*.*')):
    new_dir = file_path.replace('.', '_').replace(' ', '').split('_')[1]
    try:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(folder, new_dir))
    except WindowsError:
        # Handle the case where the target dir already exist.
        pass
    shutil.move(file_path, os.path.join(new_dir, os.path.basename(file_path)))
```

Comment: Awesome. I'm glad to have helped.